# How to determine swipe direction from gtk gesture swipe signal

Tags: touch, gtk3, vala, elementary-os

I'm trying to implement touch support for [elementaryOS' applications menu](https://github.com/elementary/applications-menu).
Unfortunately this means working on a dying language like Vala. Nonetheless I am working my way through very little documentation regarding GTK3's touch gestures support. So After adding the touch mask and connecting the touch event signal to the panel's eventBox I end up with a handler function that receives both the calling widget and a touchEvent. From here I am trying to use [GtkGestureSwipe](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.GestureSwipe.html) to determine if a swipe was completed (touch_begin, touch_update, touch_end). On the swipe signal's documentation there is mention that both velocity and direction are passed but only XY velocities are documented. I was wondering if there was a way to determine direction in a similar way as `eventScroll` which has a direction property or if the XY velocities can be interpreted as a sort of cartesian coordinate pair.

Comment: Doesn't the sign of velocity determine the direction?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev could you please elaborate? the documentation is not very explicit on how this works.

Comment: I mean, velocity can be a negative value for swipes to left or top and positive for swipes to right and bottom. That's how velocity's sign shows the direction.

Comment: Insulting the programming language you're trying to get help for is a good way to ensure you don't get any assistance from the people who are in the best position to help you with it.

Comment: @MichaelGratton please refer to: https://www.bassi.io/articles/2017/02/13/on-vala/

it is not an insult when it has been a fact for some years now

Comment: Yes yes, everyone's seen that blog post, however one person's opinion doesn't mean anything. You'd be best to look at some facts, say Vala's recent commit or release history, or say the number of projects moving away from it — none. In any case, irrespective of whether your opinion is correct, the original point still stands.

Comment: I suggest you look at vectors and cartesian plots to get some insight into how this works